# Comment dire "dossard" en japonais?

Tags: translation

Un [dossard](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dossard) est un morceau de tissu qui identifie les sportifs dans un marathon:

[image: dossard]

Comment dire ça en japonais ?

---

日本語では、フランス語の「dossard」と同じ意味の言葉がありますか？
In Japanese, is there an equivalent for the French word dossard?

Comment: ( this question is also a test for http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22 )

Comment: You've tried katakanizing the word, and googling for it, right?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: no relevant results for https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%89%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC

Comment: I think it is difficult for this site to cope with so many languages. (Since the primary user base is English-speaking)

Comment: Regarding that discussion on meta: I don't really see any consensus  pointing at accepting questions in languages other than English or Japanese. I don't have a very strong opinion, but I think it's pretty established that these are the two only viable language options for the site (beside, the name is "Japanese Language and Usage", not "Langue et Usage du Japonais" ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know French and am guessing from the result of what English websites say about it. If my understanding is correct, the Japanese counterpart is ゼッケン.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more a matter of English<->French translation than anything else. Once you know that the English word for 'dossard' is 'bib', then WWWJDIC gives you:

> ゼッケン  (n) cloth bib with number or logo worn by athletes, etc. (e.g. over their shirts) (ger: Decken)

:-)

Comment: I was about to ask in English but Wiktionary does not say "bib" for "dossard" so there might be some English subtleties I am not getting. Also, a Google Images search for "bib" shows NOT A SINGLE image of what I am looking for: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=bib

Comment: @Nicolas: that's because 'bib' can mean many things depending on context :-) For instance here: http://www.google.com/search?q=race+bib&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch

Comment: For the record, I wasn't questioning the use of the word 'dossard', but rather the fact that the entire question (and particularly title) was written in French and therefore perhaps not very accessible to the readership of this site.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I would never call that bit of cloth assigning a number to a marathon runner a "bib". To me, a "bib" is a small apron worn by small children to protect their clothing at mealtime.